# OpenGL 2 squares under each other

Tags: opengl

I want to have 2 squares under each other centered in an openGL scene.

I want it like this: https://image.prntscr.com/image/776a14cd345047a1985072e0cf279ceb.png

How can I do this, with glVertex and glColor?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your current approach and describe what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
void draw() {
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f( 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f( 1.0f,  1.0f);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f,  1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.8f);
    glVertex2f( 0.8f, 0.8f);
    glVertex2f( 0.8f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.0f);

    glVertex2f(-0.3f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f( 0.6f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f( 0.6f,-0.6f);
    glVertex2f(-0.3f,-0.6f);
  glEnd();
}
```

It was one of my better eye-balling jobs.  Output (left is mine, bottom-right is yours):

[image]

Note that I am drawing a full-screen black quad instead of what one would usually do (`glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` then `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`) since you asked specifically in terms of `glColor` and `glVertex`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have your version as well?